# Receive alarm in spite of that device has been restarted

Tags: android

I want to make an alarm clock. I've done it but it works only if device wasn't restarted.If it was I just don't get any alarm. What should I do to receive my alarm no matter has device been restarted or not?
That's how I set alarm time:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),pi1);
```

Comment: You need to create a `BacgroundService` to do that and "AutoLoad" your service on restart.

Comment: @aspicas Can you please explain it more widely? You want that I start a service which set an alarm, am I right?

Comment: Yes, the first option you need to create a `bacgroundService` with receiver on manifest which open when you PowerOn your device, later, on backgrounService you need to put your code with ÀlarmManager`

Comment: @aspicas Sorry, but how will I get time for the AlarmManager? I mean: for example we did all what you said then run our app, set alarms and somehow device was turned off and after that was turned on, here we will start our backgroundService which will set alarms in AlarmManager but since device was restarted we have no times which we have to set in AlarmManager. Can you please explain me this part? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried in a similar situation:

Make your broadcast receiver detect the system restart. Now, as soon as your system restarts, your broadcast receiver will detect it and you can perform your task. Like, in my project, I ran a query onto my SQLite database and retrieved all the alarms that have not executed and then executed them according to my requirements and updated the database with the same.

You can try something similar to it.

**Code to retrieve alarms:**

Add your Broadcast Receiver with the following attributes:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>     
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```

This BroadcastReceiver will detect your Android device's restart and execute the onReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver. In the onReceive() method, retrieve all the alarms according to your criteria and then process them further.

To learn further about how to retrieve records or tuples from the SQLite Database go through the following link:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow

Comment: Well, for now I can set only one alarm.(can't work with whole at once) What can you suggest for me?

Comment: If you just want it for one alarm, you can use the same technique (which I described above) with Shared Preferences.

Comment: If you want for multiple alarms, as soon as an alarm is set by the user, save its PendingIntent's request code and the time and date details of the alarm in the SQLite database and process all info from there.

Comment: Don't use `SharedPreferences` to do that, when you clean app data your `SharedPreferences`it's cleanned too, use `SQLite` like @VarunKumar said you then you can set more details

Comment: @varun-kumar Okay, I have an SQLite database. Can you please briefly explain me how to retrieve alarms after device has been restarted.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the explanation on how to retrieve alarms. If you still have any further doubts, feel free to ask.